# How to click the kendo dropdown in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Here is my selenium code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[id()='ddlSaleItem_listbox]")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[id()='ddlSaleItem_listbox']"))).click();
```

here is my HTML code:

```html
<div unselectable="on" style="overflow: auto; position: relative; height: auto;">
   <ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="ddlSaleItem_listbox" aria-live="polite" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox">
  <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-focused" aria-selected="true" data-offset-index="0" id="91877f7d-e75f-4218-8f6f-e87aaafe5e27">Health Club  Facility  Quarterly</li>
  <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">Hrealth Club  Half Yearly</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

please help me to get this done

Answer (score 1):

The `xpath` you used is not valid, it should be `@id` instead of `id()`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ddlSaleItem_listbox']"))).click();
// or using By.id instead of xpath
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ddlSaleItem_listbox']"))).click();
```

No need to use `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`, `elementToBeClickable` is doing it already.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, you are using wrong xpath it should be `//ul[@id='ddlSaleItem_listbox]`.

And i would suggest if `id` is available for element then better to go with it.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ddlSaleItem_listbox"))).click();
```

While handling kendo dropdown you might face problem like element not getting click and there is no error or other element getting click instead of expected one. In such case you can use `JavascriptExecutor` to perform click on intended element.

e.g.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ddlSaleItem_listbox"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 1):

To click the kendo dropdown using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("ul.k-list.k-reset#ddlSaleItem_listbox"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='k-list k-reset' and @id='ddlSaleItem_listbox']"))).click();
  ```